# Deleting Rows in Google Sheets when data only repeats in Column A

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Using Google Sheets I have almost finished a macro to create heatsheets for swim meets, but I am having trouble getting rid of the duplicate names. The data only repeats in Column A, but I want to delete the entire row when Column A does have a repeat. So in the example below I need to delete Row 3, Row 7, and Row 8.

```
Name         IM
James Smith  47.7
James Smith  48.27
Sally Baker  53.76
Katie Jones  57.63
Advay Shah   58.15
Sally Baker  58.65
Katie Jones  59.52
```

I am using the following lines of code (the spacing is wrong because I struggled with pasting into the post), but it's not doing anything when I run the macro. Obviously I have something incorrect.

```
  function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for (i in data) {
  var row = data[i];
  var duplicate = false;
  for (j in newData) {
  if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
    duplicate = true;
  }
}
if (!duplicate) {
  newData.push(row);
}
}
sheet.clearContents();
sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

Comment: You want to remove the duplicated name. When there are the duplicated names, you want to leave the 1st one. If my understanding is correct, how about modifying from ``if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {`` to ``if (row[0] == newData[j][0]) {``? ``0`` of ``row[0]`` and ``newData[j][0]`` means the column "A".

Comment: For the heats to generate correctly, the entire row which contains the duplicated names has to be deleted, but yes it has to leave the first occurrence of the name. I will give that a shot!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was solved.